# set size of tableview in ios storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want my ViewController to be shared by a tableView and a TextView, where the TextView would appear beneath the TableView. But the TableView insists on taking over the entire scene/screen. How do I set the height of the TableView in the storyboard so I can make room for my TextView? (Please notice that I am not asking for a footer, which is actually what I am trying to change from)

Comment: @Bejibun I don't understand your comment. Maybe it's due to the typo I had in the question. My problem is the the TableView has taken over the entire screen, leaving no room for anything else.

Comment: You just need to change the size of the TableView on the storyboard then.

Comment: set the delegate and datasource will be the answer

Comment: The ViewController in question is displayed inside a Container View. I don't think that's the problem. But.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a UITableViewController, which means that you get a scene with a full-screen UITableView.

To avoid this, use a normal UIViewController scene and just insert the UITableView into the interface manually (and configure its `delegate` and `dataSource` to point to the view controller).

UITableViewController is just a convenience. It doesn't do anything for you that you can't do yourself with a normal UIViewController. And in your situation, it is an inconvenience instead of a convenience.

Comment: Wow, you are a wizard! How did you know it was a TableViewController?

Comment: Your observation about UITableViewController is correct. But even after setting the bounds in the storyboard, the TableView still fills my scene/screen when I run the app. It leaves no room for the TextView, and so the textview does not appear. I spent a few hours struggling with it before asking again. But I am not succeeding.

Comment: That sounds like perhaps your constraints are incorrect. You do understand about auto layout, right?

Comment: I tried auto layout such that both views are visible in portrait and in landscape mode. That's the extend of my understanding of auto-layout. But that still does not help keep the table constrained.

Comment: I tried to do `[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100)];` but that still did not affect the size of the table. It still takes over the screen.

Comment: Maybe the textView is the problem. Now I think I manage to get the TableView to not take over the screen, but my TextView is still now showing.

Comment: Can you put the project up on github? That way I can take a look at it and, if I can solve the problem, I can push the solution back at you.

Comment: It's the auto-layout stuff. I played with that some more and part of the text is showing. I need to find a tutorial on that so I will search on Google. (I just finished a course and am trying to practice some more by creating a real app. We didn't cover auto-layout; but professor did mention it).

Answer (score 0):

Add a container view to your ViewController and link to an "external" UITableView instead of the provided UIView that comes with it when your drop it into your storyboard.
Send data via the segue, get it back via a delegate.
This way you can freely design your View with very little headaches.